# How can i get the value of attribute in of a xml node in php?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, xmldom

I'm using simplexml to read a xml file. So far i'm unable to get the attribute value i'm looking for. this is my code.

```
          if(file_exists($xmlfile)){
              $doc = new DOMDocument();
              $doc->load($xmlfile);
              $usergroup = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "preset" );
              foreach($usergroup as $group){         
                 $pname = $group->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
                 $att = 'code';
                 $name = $pname->attributes()->$att; //not working

                 $name = $pname->getAttribute('code'); //not working
                 if($name==$preset_name){
                     echo($name);
                      $group->parentNode->removeChild($group);
                 }
              }
          }
```

and my xml file looks like

```
<presets>
<preset>
 <name code="default">Default</name>
  <createdBy>named</createdBy>
  <icons>somethignhere</icons>
 </preset>
</presets>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually question in my head includes deleting a node as well , mistakenly i could not add it.  So in my point of view this is the complete answer, i a case if someone else find this useful.
This answer doesn't include SimpleXMLElement class because how hard i tried it didn't delete the node with unset(); . So back to where i was , i finally found an answer. This is my code.
and its Simple!!!

```
if(file_exists($xmlfile)){
              $doc = new DOMDocument();
              $doc->load($xmlfile);
              $presetgroup = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "preset" );
              foreach($presetgroup as $group){       
                 $pname = $group->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
                  $pcode = $pname->item(0)->getAttribute('code');
                 if($pcode==$preset_name){
                      echo($preset_name);
                      $group->parentNode->removeChild($group);
                 }
              }
          }
        $doc->save($xmlfile);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this :**

```
function getByPattern($pattern, $source)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($source);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $result = $xpath->evaluate($pattern);

    return $result;
}
```

**And you may use it like (using `XPath`) :**

```
$data = getByPattern("/regions/testclass1/presets/preset",$xml);
```

---

### UPDATE

---

**Code :**

```
<?php
    $xmlstr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><presets><preset><name code=\"default\">Default</name><createdBy>named</createdBy><icons>somethignhere</icons></preset></presets>";

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

    $result = $xml->xpath("/presets/preset/name");

    foreach($result[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
    }

?>
```

**Output :**

```
code="default"
```

---

***P.S.** And also try accepting answers as @TJHeuvel mentioned; it's an indication that you respect the community (and the community will be more than happy to help you more, next time...)*

Comment: thanks i dont understand how to get the attribute value from your code. And i have posted a wrong xml code please check the edit.

Comment: @guitarlass What is it that you don't understand? Just copy-paste the function I sent you, and use it as I've shown you (to get a specific element). if you want to get `/presets/preset/name` (= the full path to your element), then use it like `$data = getByPattern("/presets/preset/name",$xml)`. Simple as that. :-)

Comment: yes i undertand that but, how can i get the attribute `code` 's value ?

Comment: @guitarlass if you have the element stored in `$data`, then to get the `code` attribute, just try : `$data->getAttribute("code")`.

Comment: ok thanks but why doesn't my code working? i have coded `$name = $pname->getAttribute('code');`

Comment: @guitarlass IF `$pname` is what you think it is, then it SHOULD work. It's not working? Then `$pname` is most likely NOT what you think it is. Have checked the element is there?

Comment: even if i use your code i still get this error `Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute() `

Comment: @guitarlass OK, let's see. Is your xml file containing JUST what you posted in your question, or is there more to it? (if so, please repost ALL of it)

Comment: I have other blocks of <preset></preset> with different values, inside <presets> </presets>. and <icons> contains a comma separated list. thats all..

Comment: thanks so for this do i have to use get_file_contents($xml) to take it as a string?

Comment: @guitarlass if you want to directly load from a file path, try : `new SimpleXMLElement($filepath,0,true);` instead of `new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);`. :-)

Comment: yes its working thanks a lot. I hate working with file system. :( i have to include every data within xml. isn't there a easy way to execute these files? like predefined methods to delete a node, find a node .. etc ?

Comment: @guitarlass Glad to have helped! (For a complete reference on SimpleXMLElement, have a look at the documentation - there are lots of example there : http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). Also, please do accept the answer (it's a nice way for the community to see that it helped).

Comment: how can i delete the parent node <preset> using this ..? :)

Comment: @guitarlass What do you mean? Delete ALL `preset` nodes and their contents? - Have a look here : http://www.kavoir.com/2008/12/how-to-delete-remove-nodes-in-simplexml.html

Comment: no just the one that matches the attribute value im checking. thought of using`$result[0]->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild(?)` but how can i select relevant <preset> node in which <name code="default"> exists?

Comment: @guitarlass See the link on my previous comment (I *think* using `unset` might work...)

Comment: unset($xml –> presets–>preset);  will delete all the <preset> nodes?

Comment: @guitarlass Just specific a **particular** nod you want, and `unset` it.

Comment: ok, i gave it another thought , but i just dont know how to select the relevant node to delete after selecting $a which has the matching attribute value. i can get node <name> which is `$result[0]` but how can i get the parent node of <name> which is the relevant <preset> node?

Comment: @guitarlass just play with the xpath : `$result = $xml->xpath("/presets/preset");`. Btw, XPath is by far the easiest way to play with XML - for docs, have a look here : http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Please edit the relevant information into the question and/or answer, or even post new answers with new details if that is warranted. The comment section of a question/answer is only meant for relevant information regarding the actual post at hand, like mistakes, requests for more details, etc. not for long discussions even though they may be helpful to the people involved. If you need to continue this discussion, consider taking it to a chat room instead.